# How do I rotate a 3D coordinate around another coordinate?

Tags: vector, 3d, rotation, coordinates

[solved](/questions/tagged/solved)
**Sorry, I was inflating the world coordinates but not the camera coordinates.**

Before you mark this question as a duplicate, let me explain. I've managed rotate 3D vectors around its reference point (relative 0, 0, 0). And I'm using this function to rotate the 3D world around the camera to form a first person view.

[fig. 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKe3G.png)
[fig. 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVLmd.png)

As you can see in the two images, the black cuboid is rotating around an arbitrary point, but not the camera. Here's the core question.

How do I rotate a point in 3D **relative to myself**?

What I'm doing right now is this. (I've pasted in the comments too for easier reading)

```
/**
     * Translates a 3D coordinate into a renderable 2D coordinate.
     * The first element of the return value represents the X coordinate,
     * and the second element represents the Y coordinate.
     * See TCS.png in the root directory for a visual representation.
     *
     * @param coordinate Coordinate to translate
     * @return Pair of integer coordinates (first = X, second = Y)
     */
    @Nonnull
    protected Pair<Integer> translate(@Nonnull Coordinate coordinate) {
        final Coordinate adjusted = Coordinate.subtract(coordinate, origin);
        final Coordinate rotated = Coordinate.rotateAround(adjusted, origin, getRotation());

        final int fovl = 1500;

        return new Pair<>(
                (int) (fovl / (fovl + rotated.x()) * rotated.z()),
                (int) (fovl / (fovl - rotated.x()) * -rotated.y())
        );
    }
```

The data class `Pair` is a simple class with two entries: first and second.

The constant `fovl` is a part of an equation I don't fully understand yet. But I don't think it's causing the rotation issue. I've tried changing it multiple times, and the rotation didn't change.

And in the function `Coordinate.rotateAround()`, this is happening.

```
/**
     * Rotates given coordinate around the reference coordinate by given rotation.
     *
     * @param coordinate Coordinate to rotate
     * @param reference Reference point to rotate around
     * @param rotation Rotation to apply
     * @return Resulting coordinate
     */
    @Nonnull
    public static Coordinate rotateAround(
            @Nonnull Coordinate coordinate,
            @Nonnull Coordinate reference,
            @Nonnull Rotation rotation
    ) {
        // Find the relative delta
        final Coordinate delta = Coordinate.subtract(coordinate, reference);

        final Coordinate rotatedDelta = delta.toVector().rotate(rotation);

        // Return reference + delta
        return Coordinate.add(reference, rotatedDelta);
    }
```

Basically, I'm subtracting the two coordinates to find the delta vector, then rotating that vector with the camera's rotation. But this is resulting in a rotation around an arbitrary point that I did not intend it to.

Any help regarding this issue is welcomed.

For reference, z means width and x means depth in my coordinate system.

Rotation code: (Please let me know if I have an error here. I'm new to 3D coordinates)

```
/**
 * Rotates this vector by a rotation.
 *
 * @param rotation Rotation to apply
 * @return Resulting vector
 */
@Nonnull
public Vector rotate(@Nonnull Rotation rotation) {
    return plusYaw(rotation.yaw()).plusPitch(rotation.pitch()).plusRoll(rotation.roll());
}

/**
 * Rotates this vector in the Y axis by given degrees.
 *
 * @param yaw Yaw to apply
 * @return Resulting vector
 */
@Nonnull
public Vector plusYaw(double yaw) {
    return new Vector(
            x() * Math.cos(yaw) + z() * Math.sin(yaw),
            y(),
            -x() * Math.sin(yaw) + z() * Math.cos(yaw)
    );
}

/**
 * Rotates this vector in ths Z axis by given degrees.
 *
 * @param pitch Pitch to apply
 * @return Resulting vector
 */
@Nonnull
public Vector plusPitch(double pitch) {
    return new Vector(
            x() * Math.cos(pitch) - y() * Math.sin(pitch),
            x() * Math.sin(pitch) + y() * Math.cos(pitch),
            z()
    );
}

/**
 * Rotates this vector in ths X axis by given degrees.
 *
 * @param roll Roll to apply
 * @return Resulting vector
 */
@Nonnull
public Vector plusRoll(double roll) {
    return new Vector(
            x(),
            y() * Math.cos(roll) - z() * Math.sin(roll),
            y() * Math.sin(roll) + z() * Math.cos(roll)
    );
}
```